# Surround a string with markers

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file and need to surround some words with a desired string pair.

For example, i have a following file:

```
abc def
gefhi jkl
```

and want to surround all the occurrences of `ef` with `ab` and `xy`, so the result will be following:

```
abc dabefxy
gabefxyhi jkl
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{gsub(/ef/,"ab&xy");print}' input.txt
```

or

```
awk '{gsub(/ef/,"abefxy");print}' input.txt
```

output

```
abc dabefxy
gabefxyhi jkl
```

from [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

> If the special character ‘&’ appears in replacement, it stands for the
>   precise substring that was matched by regexp.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ef/abefxy/g' filename
```

test

```
$echo abc def | sed 's/ef/abefxy/g'
abc dabefxy
$echo gefhi jkl | sed 's/ef/abefxy/g'
gabefxyhi jkl
```

`s` command sustitutes any occurence of `ef` with `abefxy`

`g` command makes it global, applying to all mathches

EDIT

To match any string and surround by markers, a back reference can be used.

```
$echo abc def | sed 's/\(ef\)/ab\1xy/g'
abc dabefxy
$echo abc def | sed 's/\(ab\)/ab\1xy/g'
ababxyc def
```

`\1` selects the matched pattern in the first paranthesis pair

Comment: why not a simple `s/ef/abefxy/g`? e.g. without ```\```?

Comment: @jm666 it was a typing error. Thank you for pointing out. :) corrected in answer

Comment: Is there any way to use multiple `ef`-like strings, except for running this command once more for each input?

Comment: @fgsfds432 save the strings in a file and call sed followed by filename. See the edit in original aswer, now with the file name

Comment: @nu11p01n73R  I mean, if I would need to surround not only `ef`, but also `ab` or `hi`. Calling `sed` repeatedly on the same input may cause problems with `ab` from `gabefxyhi` being marked after the first run with `ef`, even though it was not needed.

Comment: @fgsfds432 you can use a back reference for that purpose. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to achieve this.

```
sed 's/\(ef\)/ab\1xy/'
```

You don't specify how you're reading your string, so here's my example below:

```
#!/bin/env bash

search_term='ef'
line='abc def'
echo "${line}" | sed "s/\(${search_term}\)/ab\1xy/"
```

The console output in the example above would be `abc dabefxy` as you want.

If you're looking to do replacements in a file, you can do it in-place...

```
search_term='ef'
sed --in-place "s/\(${search_term}\)/ab\1xy/" my_file.txt
```

In this example, sed will replace the first occurrence of `ef` with `abefxy` on each line of `my_file.txt`. Consider backing up your file first though.

If you wish to replace ALL occurrences of `ef` inside the string, rather than just the first occurrence. You can add the `g` (global) flag to your sed expression...

```
sed --in-place "s/\(${search_term}\)/ab\1xy/g" my_file.txt
                                            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

**Command:**

```
sed 's/ef/ab&xy/g' < file.txt
```

Here, '&' equals the matching pattern (ef). So effectively replaces "ef" with "abefxy".

**Output:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat file.txt
abc def
gefhi jkl


sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ sed 's/ef/ab&xy/g' < file.txt
abc dabefxy
gabefxyhi jkl
```